# SVN Line ending Style

Tags: svn, line-endings, eol

When i try to commit the file in SVN its showing error as "Commit failed".Details follow....commit svn: Inconsistent line ending style.

Comment: I have a scary variant of this problem: I am seeing this error message in a __streams__ library. Looking at the files giving the error, I see names like `test/unicode_demo_utf8_crlf.txt`. I suspect that these files are bloody well __supposed to__ have inconsistent line-ending style.  Unfortunately, adding `--force` to `svn import` does not sufficiently encourage subversion to shut up and read the files. Any solution? `--double-secret-force` perhaps?

Answer (score 8):

Check your svn properties on the directory / files.  If you have svn:eol-style defined, but your file contains different styles (Unix vs DOS) the commit will fail, since SVN doesn't know which to convert to.

Reference: http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2006-07/0702.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Once you're aware of the line ending style svn expects, most modern editors will have options to convert your source completely to one style or another.  You can also run regular expressions to detect and alter them (I like Perl for this).

MSDOS EOL: "\r\n"

UNIX EOL: "\n"

Comment: DOS (and Windows) use "\r\n". Additionally, Mac OS Classic (9 and below) use "\r".

Answer (score 1):

Check the EOLs in commit message itself: If you pass a commit message from file with the `--file` switch, make sure the EOL style in the **commit message** is consistent (all DOS or all UNIX).

Answer (score 1):

for followers, here's how to manually set the prop to one or the other:

```
 svn propset svn:eol-style LF path/to/filename
```

Comment: For me the fix was to delete the property

Comment: @Charbel That's not really a fix, it's just ignoring the problem. Whether that causes any real problems will depend on the other tools / languages being used.

Answer (score 0):

select line end style form your tool(like kdiff) itself...right side bottom(just above the output lines)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using TortoiseSVN in a Windows environment.  I got this same error when trying to commit project files, presumably written in Linux (an AVR32 project).  I was able to get around this problem simply by opening each file in Microsoft Visual Studio, at which point VS prompted me to normalize the line endings.  Choosing to do so caused Tortoise to stop complaining.